# How to ask for Many Extended permissions easily

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I already know that many information requires extended permissions to be accessed by the application on facebook api. This is sent as extra uri variable like "scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream" etc. Now, if I need many extended permissions, then how can i simplify it? Without mentioning all permission names individually is there any way to ask them in short cut way?

Regards

Comment: Asking for permissions is supposed to be a pain, to discourage you from requesting them unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you have to put them in the url.  whats the problem with that?

Comment: Main problem is that, it will result a really a long url in case i want to put most of the permissions. I was just curious if there is any such way to get it simply :)